# How can a Linux cpuset be iterated over with shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sysfs

Linux's sys filesystem represents sets of CPU ids with the syntax:

1. `0,2,8`: Set of CPUs containing 0, 2 and 8.
2. `4-6`: Set of CPUs containing 4, 5 and 6.
3. Both syntaxes can be mixed and matched, for example: `0,2,4-6,8`

For example, running `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online` prints `0-3` on my machine which means CPUs 0, 1, 2 and 3 are online.

The problem is the above syntax is difficult to iterate over using a for loop in a shell script. How can the above syntax be converted to one more conventional such as `0 2 4 5 6 8`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww For what it is worth, shell is a programming language and used in software development. The question is not about Linux per se (Linux is used to bring context to the problem); rather, it is about converting one string format to another. I'd say converting being string formats is in the domain of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo 0,2,4-6,8 | awk '/-/{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++)printf "%s%s",i,ORS;next} 1' ORS=' ' RS=, FS=-
0 2 4 5 6 8
```

This can be used in a loop as follows:

```
for n in $(echo 0,2,4-6,8 | awk '/-/{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++)printf "%s%s",i,ORS;next} 1' RS=, FS=-)
do
   echo cpu="$n"
done
```

Which produces the output:

```
cpu=0
cpu=2
cpu=4
cpu=5
cpu=6
cpu=8
```

Or like:

```
printf "%s" 0,2,4-6,8 | awk '/-/{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++)printf "%s%s",i,ORS;next} 1' RS=, FS=- | while read n
do
   echo cpu="$n"
done
```

Which also produces:

```
cpu=0
cpu=2
cpu=4
cpu=5
cpu=6
cpu=8
```

#### How it works

The awk command works as follows:

- `RS=,`

  This tells awk to use `,` as the record separator.

  If, for example, the input is `0,2,4-6,8`, then awk will see four records: `0` and `2` and `4-6` and `8`.
- `FS=-`

  This tells awk to use `-` as the field separator.

  With `FS` set this way and if, for example, the input record consists of `2-4`, then awk will see `2` as the first field and `4` as the second field.
- `/-/{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++)printf "%s%s",i,ORS;next}`

  For any record that contains `-`, we print out each number starting with the value of the first field, `$1`, and ending with the value of the second field, `$2`.  Each such number is followed by the Output Record Separator, `ORS`.  By default, `ORS` is a newline character.  For some of the examples above, we set `ORS` to a blank.

  After we have printed these numbers, we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` record.
- `1`

  If we get here, then the record did not contain `-` and we print it out as is.  `1` is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl one:

```
echo "0,2,4-6,8" | perl -lpe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/{$1..$2}/g; $_="echo {$_}"' | bash
```

Just convert the original string into `echo {0,2,{4..6},8}` and let bash 'brace expansion' to interpolate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
eval echo $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\+\)-\([[:digit:]]\+\)/$(seq \1 \2)/g' | tr , ' ')
```

Explanation:

1. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online` reads the file from sysfs. This can be changed to any other file such as `offline`.
2. The output is piped through the substitution `s/\([[:digit:]]\+\)-\([[:digit:]]\+\)/$(seq \1 \2)/g`. This matches something like `4-6` and replaces it with `$(seq 4 6)`.
3. `tr , ' '` replaces all commas with spaces.
4. At this point, the input `0,2,4-6,8` is transformed to `0 2 $(seq 4 6) 8`. The final step is to `eval` this sequence to get `0 2 4 5 6 8`.
5. The example `echo`'s the output. Alternatively, it can be written to a variable or used in a for loop.